# What does the 'number of guests' mean in hostels?

Tags: bookings, accommodation, terminology, hostels, booking.com

I want to book an hostel, we are two (two friends) so we need two beds in a room

I found this room:

[image]

What does the number of guests mean? how many should I select? we just need the hostel to sleep, not more

Comment: Third-party booking sites are notoriously unclear (if not actively misleading) when describing rooms and beds and capacities, especially for hostels. It's usually better to go to the hotel's site directly and see what they're offering, and to contact them if you have any questions. They can often price match a third-party site too so you can book directly.

Answer (score 3):

"Number of guests" means the number of people who will be staying in the room.  A "guest" in this context is a customer of the hotel.

Answer (score 1):

You are two guests; select "2" in the drop down. Usually his number will indicate how many beds in a dorm or other shared facility are reserved for you -- the remaining beds will be allocated to other guests. In the case of tents or private rooms, it also helps the hostel know how many you need. If you select 3 people for a 2-person tent, the hostel will reserve 2 tents.

For what it's worth, I recognize the interface in your screenshot. That particular website is rather confusing, and the price is per person, not per tent.

Comment: i want to have a room with two beds, just two for me and my friend, this is the link http://www.hostels.com/hostels/paris/le-camping-des-grands-voisins/266738?dateFrom=2016-06-14&dateTo=2016-06-17&guestCount=2&p=14#anchor=availability&priceFrom=0&priceTo=280&roomTypes=twin&propertyAnchor=p266738 will anyone share the room with us ? (notice i need two beds not one bed) beause we are just friends.

Comment: It's a hard to tell for sure from the screenshot of that website, so I checked Le Camping des Grands Voisins on another booking website that makes a more clear differentiation between private and shared rooms.  I found out their tents are "private", which means they aren't dormitory style and you wouldn't be sharing the tent with anyone else.

Comment: If there are two beds, and you tell them that there are two guests, you will have the room to yourself. There is a slight chance that they put you in one room and your friend in another, but you will not be required to share a bed. Since these sites are built around a "dorm" concept, you are effectively reserving "a bed" per guest (how I like to think of it), so you should put how many people and not how many rooms you want.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas oh another problem then, we need one room so we can leave our passports and our presents in the room while we are seeing the sites. :( help please

Comment: I would never leave my passport at a hostel. Just book a private room that says it sleeps 2, and put that you have 2 guests. Usually this will end up being one room for both of you. Otherwise look for a place that includes storage lockers among their amenities and bring your own locks.